# Copy a Binary file 32 bytes per 32 bytes

Tags: c, bin

What i'm trying to do here, is to copy a binary file 32 bytes per 32 bytes.
WHY am i trying to do that ? because i need to send this binary file on the USART of my board. I cannot send it in one shot, that's why i send it 32 bytes per 32 bytes.

First, i try to read my binary file into a buffer and write it in another file 3é bytes per 32 bytes.
The problem is, when i try to execute the new binary file i made.. it doesn't execute on the board and i don't understand why

here's my code if you want to give a try ..

```
int sendBuff(char *buffer,int *size)
{
    int i,n =0;
    char c ;
    FILE *file,target;

    //Open file
    file = fopen("Nucleo-L152RE_bis.bin", "rb");

    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", "Nucleo-L152RE_bis.hex");
        return 0;
    }
    *size = getFileSize(file);


    if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    //Read file contents into buffer
    fread(buffer,*size, 1, file);



    fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
void writefile(unsigned char *buffer,int size){

    FILE *file;
    int i;
    file = fopen("salut.bin", "a");
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", "Nucleo-L152RE.bin");

    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(unsigned char),size,file);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

and the main function :

```
int main()
{
    /* variables locales */
    unsigned char bufferS[1000000];
    int nId = 5, nChoice, nBytesWritten, nBytesRead;
    int* pByteRead, pByteWritten;
    int size;
    int k = 0,k_hexa = 0;

    /* demande du numéro du port COM */



    /* boucle tant que l'on ne quitte pas */
    do
    {
        /* menu */


            //ecriture de l'executable dans un buffer
            sendBuff(bufferS, &size);
            printf("size of file: %d\n\n", size);
            k = 0;


            printf("SIZE : %d\n", size);

            //send program

            do
            {

                 printf("Envoi de donnees...\r\n");

                //WriteCOM(bufferS + k, 32, &nBytesWritten);
                writefile(bufferS+k,32);
                printf("%d octet(s) envoye(s) et k : %d .\r\n",
                        nBytesWritten, k);



                k += 32;

                // scanf("%d",&nChoice);
            } while (k < size);

       }
}
```

Comment: is it on windows? If yes, shouldn't you use "ab" instead of "a" in fopen?

Comment: There are also a few other flaws that may or may not be relevant: are you sure that the file size is a multiple of 32? Shouldn't bufferS  be allocated dynamically? (Btw you could of course work without bufferS)

Comment: BTW, you generally should use much larger buffers than 32 bytes. Using 8192 bytes buffers should be more sensible!

Comment: i find it a bit confusing that you name your function sendBuff when it in fact reads. you should also check return value of fread to make sure you really got the number of bytes you expected (`bytesRead = fread(buffer,1,*size,fp)`)

Comment: in general you should check return values of runtime functions, especially concerning I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)According to your implement,
**you add extra (32-size%32) redundant bytes to the new salut.bin**,
which result in the failure execution. The copy will be OK just like this way,

```
           do
           {
                printf("Envoi de donnees...\r\n");

                //WriteCOM(bufferS + k, 32, &nBytesWritten);
                writefile(bufferS+k,32);
                printf("%d octet(s) envoye(s) et k : %d .\r\n",
                        nBytesWritten, k);
                k += 32;

                // scanf("%d",&nChoice);
            } while (k < size-32);
            writefile(bufferS+k, size%32);
```

2)The wrong bin format or content would result in `execute failure`, sometimes which is caused by missing some bytes or adding redundant bytes in the end of file by chance.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, Thanks. And I edit again to add back missing part of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Should we refer to the code which you posted as is? In that case you seem to be trigerring undefined behaviour because you try to read value of `nBytesWritten` inside `printf`. But `nBytesWritten` does not seem to be initialized.

Comment: I don't think so, "fopen("salut.bin", "a");" means append.

Comment: Your revised answer is no longer really useful, as this applies only to the debug output.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: What do you mean if user is referring to this code, there is UB, so anything might happen

Comment: Currently the value of nBytesWritten is only relevant to the printf. Even if this small flaw is fixed, his real problem would still be there.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: Please read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Yes, but this will only affect the printf, i.e. the value of nBytesWritten. The value can be 0, 33, 568, or whatever. But it won't have any effect on further things.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: If you trigger undefined behaviour, this will affect *everything*

Comment: @kidz55: It is not that it is useful if you are running your code like that and there is UB anything may happen, please read more about undefined behaviour

Comment: alright , i removed the printf and it doesn't work.. my BIN is not readable on my board and i don't know why ..

Comment: what is your board? and what you mean readable? this comment was here for you also to watch out to not have uninitialized variables in other places too

Comment: @kidz55 have you tried changing "a" to "ab"? Are you on windows? And is it your intend to open the file each time, or do you just want to write in 32 byte blocks? And have you verified that the file size is a multiple of 32? Because it won't work if it isn't.

Comment: my board is an stm32l152re and what i mean by readable is : the bin cannot execute like my other good binary files. and i noticed that my new bin file got 24 bytes more than the old bin but i can't figure why..

Comment: Check also `ab` suggestion. If you are referring to `WriteCom` function keep in mind sometimes such functions don't write all bytes so you need to check their return value

Comment: @kidz55 well yes... this suggests it is changing LF into CR LF when writing. That is why I asked you whether you're on windows, so to force to use binary mode.

Comment: yes i'm on windows . and i checked the ab suggestion and it doesn't work .. I